# REST API connection using Palantir Fondry

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

How can I create REST API data connection using Palantir Foundry?
I need to make one REST API call. I need to capture its response in Foundry dataset.

Comment: Hi Aniket and welcome to stack overflow. Please include technical details on what you are trying to achieve, as well as the problem you are facing in the form of a question. Otherwise the question doesn't really fit within stackoverflow's Q&A guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: These questions may help answer your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298172/full-example-of-magritte-rest-config
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955437/in-foundry-how-can-i-parse-a-dataframe-column-that-has-a-json-response